# Redirect user to a different page when Browser back button is pressed

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net

I have 3 pages: `Page1.aspx`, `Page2.aspx`, `Page3.aspx`

The user goes from `Page1.aspx` to `Page2.aspx`.

On `Page2`, if the browser back button is pressed I want to redirect the user to `Page3.aspx`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Also, one should never try to override the default behavior of browsers.

Comment: It is not good override mainstream browser behaviors, if user clicked back button, its assumed that he wants to go back, not to be redirected to another page. Maybe other approach would be better for this.

Answer (score 0):

A quick Google reveals. Possibly try Google first?

http://www.hunlock.com/blogs/Mastering_The_Back_Button_With_Javascript

However as has already been mentioned, changing the browser behaviour is generally a no no.